# I have created a multi field in elastisearch but it's not returning any data

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, field

I have created a multi field mapping with this

```
PUT products/product/_mapping
{
"product": {
  "properties": {
     "brand": {
        "type": "multi_field",
        "fields": {
            "brand_original": {"type": "string"},
            "raw": {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

Then I try to do a query but I don't get any result:

```
GET products/product/_search
{
     "_source": [ "brand.raw"],
    "query" : {
       "match" : {
        "brand.raw" : "clinique"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Am I missing something? It's possible to re-edit the mapping?

Comment: Can you post some example data, that you have indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Multi-fields are dead.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html)

Try this:

I created an index like this:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/product/_mapping
{
   "product": {
      "properties": {
         "brand": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "analyzed", 
            "fields": {
               "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And added a couple of documents:

```
POST /test_index/product/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"brand":"first/brand"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"brand":"second/brand"}
```

Now if I query with a `"match"` like this, I'll get back both documents

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "brand": "first/brand"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.2712221,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2712221,
            "_source": {
               "brand": "first/brand"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.028130025,
            "_source": {
               "brand": "second/brand"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But if I query against `"brand.raw"` I'll only get back the document that's an exact match:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "brand.raw": "first/brand"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.30685282,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
               "brand": "first/brand"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d2cee47ccff751955235e1efae7fce1b224dd35c

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the stupid question Google it was returning the documentation for 0.9 elasticsearch version :( and I didn't realize. By the way now I have a lot of fields for brand is possible to delete this fields or I have to recreate the index.

Comment: You can't really delete fields. I mean, you could reindex individual documents without those fields, but if you're going to do that for every document it's probably just as easy to rebuild the index.